# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException on cursor.getString(i)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method in my code that checks for the database content. Below is the code:

```
    if(rowId  >= 1){

        Cursor cursor = adapter.fetchAllQRurl();
        int length = cursor.getCount();

        for( int i=0; i<length ; i++){
           if(contents.equals(cursor.getString(i))){
          Toast.makeText(this, "The entry already exists.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

But i always get the error below. I'm not sure what went wrong on "cursor.getString(i)"
Did i miss something on my code?

```
 android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 5
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getShort(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to get values from the Cursor. 
You need to place your cursor position to the start so that it will returns values

```
Cursor cursor = adapter.fetchAllQRurl();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String Test = mNotesCursor.getString("Your_Column_Name");
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way to fetch the data from Cursor object is:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(i);
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: i tried this one: for( int i=0; i<=length ; i++){ if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ do{ String data = cursor.getString(1); Toast.makeText(this, data , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }while(cursor.moveToNext()); } } cursor.close(); but i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method) at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:363)

Comment: why are you putting this cursor code inside the for loop, no need to put it.

Comment: Because the columnIndex should not be hardcoded. So my way to do it is to put the cursor code inside the for loop to specify which column to get the String.  Another question, how do i specify the row number? the exception says "get field slot from row 0 col 1", did i understood it correctly that i have to specify it? i'm sorry if i have lots of questions. i'm new at this. thanks.

Comment: i now get the concept. but i still don't understand why i'm having that exception. the one with  "get field slot from row 0 col 1"

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

- You need to move to the first row before trying to access the columns using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()
- `cursor.getCount()` returns the number of rows. However, in your loop you are using `cursor.getString(i)`, which is used to access the n:th column.